# How to fix redirection of Post/Page of wordpress inside the wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have Wordpress inside the wordpress root. For example `www.test.com` (main site) then i have additional wordpress which is `www.test.com/media` (child). Everything is good, but except for posts and pages.

For example I created 1 post in child site, `www.test.com/media/1`. It's always redirecting to 404 page of the main site, then redirected to the main site.

here's the htaccess of the main site.

```html
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Deny from all
</Files>

<Files wp-login.php>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
    #Allow from 127.0.0.1
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "ENTER YOUR NAME & PASSWORD TO LOGIN"
    AuthUserFile /home/website/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    Satisfy any
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On


    RewriteBase /
    #RewriteRule Something.sso - [L]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|css|js|swf|jpeg|jpg|jpe|png|ico|swd|pdf|svg|eot|ttf|woff)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/Something.sso/)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

This is my subdirectory .htaccess

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase . /media/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: So what have you done to make that second Wordpress handle any requests for URLs starting with `/media/`?

Comment: @CBroe  site address, wordpress url in general settings. I can access the www.test.com/media. I also saved the permalink. The only permalink that works is https://test.com/media/?p=123. The rest will only redirect to error 404 page of main directory  (wordpress). `https://test.com`.

Comment: _"I can access the www.test.com/media"_ - because that is a physically existing directory. But `/media/1` does not exist, so the .htaccess of the WP installation on the top level will rewrite that to its own index.php. You will need to add something that lets those requests "reach" the second WP to begin with.

Comment: Yes, that's why when i tried to access other pages in subdirectory always redirect to main directory. Any suggestion to reach those requests? @CBroe

Comment: Do you have another htaccess in `media` folder ? If not then create a separate htaccess file in that folder and add this line `RewriteEngine on` to activate the htaccess.

Comment: hello @AmitVerma, i have already .htaccess in media folder. I updated the question with code of .htaccess. And i have `RewriteEngine On` on it.

Comment: Ah I just saw your edit:) change `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` to `RewriteRule . /media/index.php [L]` and remove the `RewriteBase` line

Comment: @AmitVerma tried it, still redirecting to www.test.com 404 page. Tried clearing cache and cookies. still the same.

Comment: You're still going to need to add an exception to your .htaccess on the top level, otherwise requests like `/media/does-not-physically-exist` will never reach that sub-folder .htaccess to begin with. (And then you still need WP to play ball, which it might not do without modifications, because IIRC it takes the path from $_SERVER.)

Comment: Go to your `/media/wordpress` general settings and change the `site url` and WordPress url to `https://example.com/media`

Comment: @CBroe yes thank you, that's the direction i need to figure out.

Comment: hello @AmitVerma, yes i already modified the general settings and site url.

Comment: Something like `RewriteRule ^media/ - [L]` added to the top level .htaccess (before the existing rules) should at least let the requests pass through to the second one. Try that, and see if you at least get the 404 page of the second WP then.

Comment: @CBore your suggestion should definitely work! ++ to your comment.

Comment: @CBroe still didn't work, tried to clear cache and cookie. I think i need to disable all the plugin to check if something mess up the redirections something.

Comment: This question could be on-topic here, but you would probably get better answers if you asked it at [wordpress.se] instead.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone struggling to fix these. recently i found the best method to make it work.
In your main wordpress which in my case is ([www.test.com](http://www.test.com)). Add this to your root/index.php. Change `media` to your subdirectory wordpress.

```html
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/media") === 0)
{
    require (dirname(__FILE__) . '/media/index.php');
}
else
{
    define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

    /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
    require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
}
```